# Windows 10 - Change Folder Selection Dialog

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

Many applications, including many installers, make you choose a folder using this guy:

[image: windows folder browse dialog]

Does anyone know of a procedure for changing this to use either the normal explorer file select dialog or a application/mod to change it into something else entirely?

Comment: Programs get to choose which one they want. You would have to change the program. The interface is different.

Comment: Check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.8 for example but it's possible to program an entirely different/custom folder selection dialogue interface I suppose for certain applications you can adjust the source code if that's what you are asking. If you are asking about the default folder browser dialogue, then you likely won't be able to easily change that if it's even possible as John indicated in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is built into Windows and Windows Explorer. Even if you use an Explorer Replacement (I use xPlorer2) the Windows dialogue is still used. You cannot change that feature.